# Dynamics 365 - Portals - Cannot create new Entity Form

Tags: dynamics-365, adxstudio-portals, dynamics-crm-portals

I'm new to portal in dynamics. I have created a custom entity and want to expose it out to the portal. I can't seem to create a new entity form to achieve this.

No entities are appearing for the "Entity Name" and no forms are appearing for the "Form Name" fields. Is it due to a rights issue perhaps?

[Please see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BINRO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entity form doesnt look correct, there should be some special fields that load on the right hand side whihc allow selection.

Perhaps try a different browswer or machine? Try a different CRM installation? Test as a system administration (in case of a permission issue)?

[image]

Comment: I tried Internet Explorer and the dropdowns above are now appearing, issue seems to have been with FireFox. Thanks a lot got your help.